# nginx rewrite ends up in wrong folder

Tags: nginx, path, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set up a few rewrite rules in nginx to simplify php uris, but
I can't seem to get it working and I couldn't find an answer anywhere else either. Here is a simple example of the problem:

Let's say I have a file `test.html` in the root folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
Test
<img src="img/image.jpg">
</body></html>
```

All I want to do is that a url like http://example.com/test/ would show the html page.

With this rule

```
rewrite ^/test/$ /test.html last;
```

the site is loaded but the server seems to end up in the 'wrong' path. The image cannot be displayed because the server is looking for it at `/test/img/image.jpg` instead of `/img/image.jpg`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have relative path in html and browser looks for image relative to current path, which is /test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is:

```
rewrite ^/test/$ /test.html last;
rewrite ^/test/(.*)$ /$1 last;
```

The first rule will redirect `http://example.com/test/` to your `test.html` file. Now that `test.html` loads with the new base path, `/test`, all subsequent relative URLs defined in the HTML file will load under this path which includes `img/image.jpg`. This is the correct behavior.

The second line I have added will resolve all relative paths in `test.html` to be relative to its base directory, `/`.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm just wondering what's better, this second rule to resolve relative paths or simply always using absolute paths in the first place.

Comment: @Anton, Absolute URLs are generally the best practice.